# Specify deployment path when deploying to GAE?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I have a GWT app that runs locally using GAE GoogleAppEngine already. Everything works fine and is deployed to the war folder `src/main/webapp`.

appengine.xml is located at: `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml`

Problem: when I `rightclik project > Google > Deploy to App Engine`, then Eclipse tells me that `appengine-web.xml` could not be found under `target\project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF`. Which is true as this only contains the `classes` folder. BUT why is this target folder generated at all?

When deploying locally, everything is just placed in `src\main\webapp` and works fine. How can I tell the Eclipse Google Plugin to look at this location, and not at  target`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:
search for "target" on the whole project, which should bring up 2 config files: `org.eclipse.wst.common.component`, `com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.prefs`. replace the target path with: "/src/main/webapp"...